# Did I ask a question, now deleted, tagged [psycholinguistics]?

Tags: support, questions

My [Deleted Recent Questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/50720)
 page exhibits no questions tagged [psycholinguistics], but I thought I asked one?

Answer (score 5):

The Recently deleted list only goes back a month or so.

Moderators do have access to the `deleted:1` search criterion, but there seems little point 
in reproducing the output here. If it's mod-only data, we're actually prohibited from doing that; but you may be able to see deleted questions in your [questions list](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/50720/greek-area-51-proposal?tab=questions) and deleted questions there may be available to 10k users too. If not, I'm afraid that's too bad.

I **can** say that I can't see a question from you tagged  [psycholinguistics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psycholinguistics).

Clicking that tag link shows only three over the last four years, and none that have been deleted, which is slightly odd because there are actually seven. [One of those is recent](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497057/), but it was asked on a different account. The question was closed as opinion-based after a week and then automatically cleared up ten days after that.

Comment: Can mods see more deleted questions than 10K users (assuming they have a link, not just in search)?

Comment: @JJJ I believe 10k users can see any question they can get to. Finding them might be more difficult if the search criterion isn't available.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I believe is something was deleted for being spam/rude/abusive the content of it is hidden from everyone but mods. (Not that it applies here)

Comment: @ColleenV then it reads *"This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details."* I was thinking more along the lines of questions that are hard deleted, for example to remove sensitive information (e.g. addresses of users), I'm not sure if mods can see those or if that's only for site administrators. Anyway, not really relevant since it doesn't seem to happen often (well, I think ;p).

Comment: There is a separate redaction process to remove sensitive information from revision histories. I’m sure there is a way for the CM team to delete posts so that mods can’t see them, but I don’t know of any other differences between mods/10K users than the spam content.